# Floating points : Is it true if a > b then a - b > 0?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

in c++ for two doubles a and b, is it true if a > b, then a - b > 0? Assume a, b are not Nan, just normal numbers

Comment: For `a> b` to be true, a, b can not be Nan, so assumption is not needed.

Answer (score 7):

No, not by the requirements of the C++ standard alone. C++ allows implementations to use floating-point types without support for subnormal numbers. In such a type, you could have `a` equal to 1.0001<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>*m*</sup>, where *m* is the minimum normal exponent, and `b` equal to 1.0000<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>*m*</sup>. Then `a > b` but the exact value of `a-b` is not representable (it would be subnormal), so the computed result is zero.

This does not happen with IEEE-754 arithmetic,  which supports subnormals. However, some C++ implementations, possibly not conforming to the C++ standard, use IEEE-754 formats but flush subnormal results to zero. So this will also produce `a > b` but `a-b == 0`.

Supposing an implementation is supporting subnormals and is conforming to the C standard, another issue is the standard allows implementations to use extra precision within floating-point expressions. If your `a` and `b` are actually expressions rather than single objects, it is possible that the extra precision could cause `a > b` to be true while `a-b == 0` is false. Implementations are permitted to use or not use such extra precision at will, so `a > b` could be true in some evaluations and not others, and similarly for `a-b == 0`. If `a` and `b` are single objects, this will not happen, because the standard requires implementations to “discard” the excess precision in assignments and casts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true in IEEE-754 arithmetic, in all rounding modes. So long as your C++ compiler uses IEEE-754 semantics (either via software or hardware). But see Eric Postpischill's answer for when particular implementations might diverge from IEEE-754. Best to check with your compiler documentation.